# SQL Dynamic Column Reuse

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
Select 
   DateAdd(month, 1, DateField) as MyNewDate, 
   CASE WHEN MyNewDate < GetDate() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Expired
End
```

I would like to reuse the calculation in the `DateAdd` without reevaluating the `DateAdd` for the `Expired` column. In reality the query is a lot more complex than this simple dateAdd.

The error I get is :

> *Invalid column name 'MyNewDate'.*

How can I reuse the dynamic column?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use an alias in the same query.

You need something like this

```
SELECT MyNewDate, CASE WHEN MyNewDate < GetDate() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Expired
FROM
(
    Select DateAdd(month, 1, DateField) as MyNewDate...
)
```

or retype it like

```
Select 
   DateAdd(month, 1, DateField) as MyNewDate, 
   CASE WHEN DateAdd(month, 1, DateField) < GetDate() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Expired
End
```

Comment: Problem is that then I lose MyNewDate from main select.

Comment: No you don't. I updated my answer. You have all the columns that are in your subSelect

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MyNewDate,
   CASE WHEN MyNewDate < GetDate() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Expired
(
Select 
   DateAdd(month, 1, DateField) as MyNewDate
FROM tab 
)
```